# GCC linking to a shared object's linker name

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, shared-objects

Suppose I have:

- `/usr/lib/libsomething.so.1` on machine A;
- `/usr/lib/libsomething.so.2` on machine B.

Both machines have `/usr/lib/libsomething.so` symlinking to their respective libs.

If I link using `gcc` with `-lsomething` (or even `/usr/lib/libsomething.so`) it will follow the symlink, and `ldd` on machine A produces something like:

```
libsomething.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsomething.so.1
```

This means it won't be able to find the library on machine B.

Now I know these are major version number changes and I know they may not be compatible, but I'm willing to take that risk. What I'd like to tell the linker is to look for `libsomething.so`, and don't follow the symlink so `ldd` will show

```
libsomething.so => /usr/lib/libsomething.so.1
```

on A but

```
libsomething.so => /usr/lib/libsomething.so.2
```

on B. And then the loader will follow the symlink to whatever version is there.

Also, I don't want delayed loading with dlopen or anything. I want it to link to the shared object at compile time.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Making executable which uses any available version of shared library is, of course, possible.**

The problem was that you linked your executable to version-specific *soname* (`libsomething.so.1` and `libsomething.so.2`). You should have done it with unversioned soname `libsomething.so` instead.

In order to achieve this, on the build machine you should compile and install library with soname (ELF `SONAME`) equal to `libsomething.so` (without version) so that linker can choose this soname while executable is built.

According to the [Shared Libraries HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN95), you can pass required unversioned *soname* while building the library:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsomething.so -o libsomething.so.X objectsomething.o
```

Then, as soon as you install the library and run `ldconfig`, you have:

- symlink `/lib/libsomething.so` pointing to `/lib/libsomething.so.1` on machine A;
- symlink `/lib/libsomething.so` pointing to `/lib/libsomething.so.2` on machine B.

The loader (run `ldd`) will choose unversioned symlinks regardless where it points to:

- `libsomething.so => /lib/libsomething.so (0xNNNNNNNN)` on machine A;
- `libsomething.so => /lib/libsomething.so (0xNNNNNNNN)` on machine B.

Linux dynamic loader (`ld.so`) resolves libraries based on their soname value written in the executable (ELF `NEEDED`). The value is copied from library file (ELF `SONAME`) while building the executable. As long as there is a symlink on the target system matching the soname recorded in the executable, the library pointed by this symlink will be loaded.

---

**Let's run through your setup and show commands to verifing assumptions.**

I used Fedora 18 `X86_64` for the test and adjusted output to `i686` for clarity.

- Compile both `libsomething.so.1` and `libsomething.so.2`. Make sure `SONAME` is set to unversioned `libsomething.so`:

  ```
  readelf -a libsomething.so.1 | grep SONAME
  0xNNNNNNNN (SONAME)             Library soname: [libsomething.so]

  readelf -a libsomething.so.2 | grep SONAME
  0xNNNNNNNN (SONAME)             Library soname: [libsomething.so]
  ```
- Install the libraries into their respective machines under `/lib/` directory. Run `ldconfig -v` on both machines and verify the output.

  ```
  ldconfig -v 2>&1 | grep something
  libsomething.so -> libsomething.so.1 (changed)

  ldconfig -v 2>&1 | grep something
  libsomething.so -> libsomething.so.2 (changed)
  ```
- Compile executable and make sure that it refers to the same soname without version in `NEEDED`.

  ```
  readelf -a executable | grep NEEDED
  0xNNNNNNNN (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsomething.so]
  ```
- You executable depends on unversioned `libsomething.so` now. Copy executable to both machines and run `ldd` against both copies.

  ```
  ldd executable
  libsomething.so => /lib/libsomething.so (0xNNNNNNNN)
  ```

  The last output is the same on both machines as the executable was built with soname without version. This makes loader take unversioned symlinks on targets machines. And depending on the machine, the symlink can point to different implementation of the library `libsomething.so.1` or `libsomething.so.2`.

Comment: I wasn't building the library in question, I think the real answer is just to not do what I suggested, and if you really want to cheat, just use symlinks. This provided some good info though so I am accepting.

Answer (score 2):

> This means it won't be able to find the library on machine B.

And it's not supposed to anyway.

By the very definition of [soversions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libtool-versioning.html#Libtool-versioning), `libsomething.so.2` denotes that the API/ABI is incompatible to `libsomething.so.1`. Therefore, just adding `libsomething.so` in the program's table of libraries to be loaded would be factually wrong. The `libsomething.so` symlink merely serves as a hint to ld as to which soversion to pick by default.

Of whatever file ld actually ended up opening, it will take the DTNAME/SONAME field to encode in the program. If you don't want that, don't equip libsomething with a soname. But it can easily become pain... starting with running into unavailable symbols when trying to run the program.